# How to get the all the lines with any null value with python pandas?

Tags: pandas

I mean in a csv file, maybe some column of some line is null, I want to get the lines with any of its item is null.
For example,

```
Name Age Sex
Tom   12  M
Anna  21  F
Andy  31
Monna     F
```

Then Andy and Monna has some value which is null, and I want them.

Comment: Sorry is your csv really formatted like this or is it delimited with a comma `,`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataframe has method isnull:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(//your file)
df = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```